# Unique homomorphism from the semiproduct of two groups to a third? (Universal property)

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

"Let $\phi : H \rightarrow Aut(N)$ be a group homomorphism (H and N are groups).
Define two group homomorphisms:
$\epsilon_N : N \rightarrow N \rtimes_\phi H$ which maps $n$ to $(n,1)$ and
$\epsilon_H : H \rightarrow N \rtimes_\phi H$ which maps $h$ to $(1,h)$.

Let $f_N : N \rightarrow G$ and $f_H : H \rightarrow G$ be group homomorphisms that satisfy:
$f_H(h)f_N(n)f_H(h)^{-1}=f_N(\psi_h(n))$

Show that there exists a unique group homomorphism $f : N \rtimes_\phi H \rightarrow G$ satisfying $f \circ \epsilon_N = f_N$ and $f \circ \epsilon_H = f_H$."

$\dots$

All my attempts to construct such a homomorphism have been in vain, I figured $f((n,h))$ would simply equal a product such as $f_N(n)f_H(g)$ or $f_N(\psi_h(n))f_H(h)$, but then I can't prove $f$ is a homomorphism if G is not abelian, so I can't even prove existance, let alone uniqueness. I tried constructing a picture of the mappings and that didn't help, so I'm led to believe I don't have to actually construct $f$, but there is some rules about semiproducts or something about the relation $f_N(\psi_h(n))$ holds that I am not picking up on.

Comment: What is $\psi_h(n)$?

Comment: When they write something like $(n, h)$, is that $(n, 1)(1, h)$ or $(1, h)(n,1)$?

Comment: $\psi_h(n)$ is an element of $Aut(N)$ arising from $\phi$ that is acting on some  element $n \in N$.

Comment: $(n,h)$ could be written as $(n,1)(1,h)$, $(1,h)(n,1)$ would be equivalent to $(\psi_h(n),h)$

Comment: @FeebleMindedMan Well then to make it a group homomorphism, at the very least you need $f((n,h))=f((n,1)(1,h))=f((n,1))f((1,h))=f_N(n)f_H(h)$. The rest is just mechanical checking.

Comment: @BobJones I feel like that gives me the proof of uniqueness, however if $f=f_Nf_H$ then $f((n,h)(x,y))=f_N(n)f_H(h)f_N(x)f_H(y)$ which doesn't seem to be $f((n,h))f((x,y))$ unless I can switch the order of $f_H(h)f_N(x)$ but G is not necessarily abelian so I don't think $f$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: How did you get that equality? That is exactly equal to $f((n,h))f((x,y))$ by definition, but it's not equal to $f((n,h)(x,y))$ yet. What is $(n, h)(x, y)$? Use the definition of direct product to write this as a single pair.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant to say $f((n,h))f((x,y))$ initially. Direct product gives $(nx,hy)$ so $f((nx,hy))=f_N(nx)f_H(hy)=f_N(n)f_N(x)f_H(h)f_H(y)$ which still is not $f((n,h))f((x,y))$ unless it commutes in the middle, unless I'm missing something. @BobJones

Comment: @BobJones never mind, I think I got it. It doesn't work with direct product, but it works with semidirect product and then using the identity $f_N(\psi_h(x))$ agrees with. Thanks a lot for your help.